# PowerApps Connector with Azure APIM in ASE

Tags: azure-api-management, powerapps

I have a question around connecting PowerApps to an Azure API Management which is in ASE. Also the ASE is internal and not exposed to Internet. The PowerApps application we want to develop is also for our Internal use only and need not be exposed externally.

So my question is that can we have a PowerApps application connecting to an API Management which is Internal?

Comment: Few Additions: We are not exposing any API's over the internet and is locked to ASE. Also this the Application we want to build using Power Apps would be also internal. So wanted to know if the API's have to be exposed to internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could create another VNET, add APIM into that VNET using internal mode (this will block access to APIM from outside of VNET), and setup peering between APIM's VNET and ASE's VNET. Then your whole infrastructure will not be accessible from outside, but APIM will be able to talk to ASE and other way around.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vitaliy. But my issues is PowerApps can only call API's exposed to internet. If the APIM is just Internal I think PowerApps cant access them? Is that right?

Comment: Most likely yes, you'll have to open something in vnet to make PA call it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you are trying to do: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/apimanagement/2017/09/22/export-apis-to-microsoft-powerapps-and-flow/

Hopefully that helped!

Comment: Thanks Emily. This is exactly what I want. But issue is that the APIM is not exposed to internet. I believe, to consume any API at PowerApps it has to be exposed to internet. The PowerApp application I would like to build also would be internal.